# How to visible label by condition in React KendoUI Chart

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui

How to show chart label with conditional checking series item value. Show only value > 0.

```js
const seriesData = [0, 40, 45, 30, 42, 0];
const ChartContainer = () => (
  <Chart>
    <ChartSeries>
      <ChartSeriesItem type="column" data={seriesData}>
        <ChartSeriesLabels
          visible={true}
          position={"center"}
          background={"transparent"}
          color="black"
          font="bold 16px Arial, sans-serif"
        />
      </ChartSeriesItem>
    </ChartSeries>
  </Chart>
);
```

Please help, this is my codesandbox link.
https://codesandbox.io/s/red-snowflake-osvww1?file=/app/main.jsx

Answer (score 0):

You can override the label content: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/charts/chart/elements/labels/

In your case:

```
const labelContent = (e) => e.value > 0 ? e.value : "";

<ChartSeriesLabels
      visible={true}
      position={"center"}
      background={"transparent"}
      color="black"
      font="bold 16px Arial, sans-serif"
      content={labelContent}
/>
```